# Threading Problem Kivy image texture not updating when threading is used

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I am trying to make a  application using Kivy that use threading. The background thread updates the texture in the Image Widget main class.

The problem is that the texture variable gets updated but is not displayed in the kivy Gui app

The here's the code 
I have used **ObjectProperty** to trigger update both **label:text** and  the **Image:Texture** But only the **Label:text** gets really updated

```
import random
import threading

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.core.image import Texture

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

Builder.load_string('''
<Main>:

    btn1:btn1
    label1:label1
    img1:img1
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size:root.width,root.height
        Button:
            text:"Hello"
            id:btn1
            on_release:root.btn()

        Label:
            id:label1
            text:"hello"
        Image:
            id:img1

''')


class Main(Widget):
    btn1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    label1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    img1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    a = ObjectProperty(1)
    newtexture = ObjectProperty(2)



    update = False
    iter = 1

    def btn(self):
        self.update = not self.update
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.updateValue)
        t1.start()
        # self.updateValue()

    def updateValue(self):
        while (self.update):
            self.a += 2

            testexture = Texture.create(size=(512, 512), colorfmt='rgb')
            size = 512 * 512 * 3

            if self.iter == 1:
                buf = [int(x % 128) for x in range(size)]
                self.iter = 0
                # print("strip")
            else:
                buf = [int(x % 256) for x in range(size)]
                self.iter = 1
                # print("random")

            buf = bytearray(buf)
            testexture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            self.newtexture = testexture
            # print("Generated")

    def on_a(self, instance, value):
        print('My property a changed to', value)
        self.label1.text = str(value)

    def on_newtexture(self, instance, value):
        self.img1.texture = value
        self.img1.canvas.ask_update()
        print("updated texture")
        print(value)

class MaainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


MaainApp().run()
```

Another thing if you Remove the While loop in update And Threading , and just trigger trigger with button it works perfectly fine . But that is of no use to me for  my App

please can any one tell whats actually happening and how can I update the image texture using thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been bitten by what I think is the same problem that you are encountering. As I am sure you know, changes to the GUI must be made on the main thread. Your `on_a()` and `on_newtexture()` will always be run on the main thread, so it would seem that everything is fine in that area. However, the `Texture` class handles `OpenGL` textures and I believe that forces the same constraint on using the `blit_buffer()` method of `Texture`. So here is a modified version of your `Main` `Widget` that works for me, using `Clock.schedule_once()` to get the call to `blit_buffer()` back on the main thread:

```
class Main(Widget):
    btn1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    label1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    img1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    a = ObjectProperty(1)
    newtexture = ObjectProperty(2)

    update = False
    iter = 1

    def btn(self):
        self.update = not self.update
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.updateValue, daemon=True)
        t1.start()
        # self.updateValue()

    def updateValue(self):
        while (self.update):
            self.a += 2

            testexture = Texture.create(size=(512, 512), colorfmt='rgb')
            size = 512 * 512 * 3

            if self.iter == 1:
                buf = [int(x % 128) for x in range(size)]
                self.iter = 0
                # print("strip")
            else:
                buf = [int(x % 256) for x in range(size)]
                self.iter = 1
                # print("random")

            buf = bytearray(buf)
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.updateTexture, testexture, buf))
            # print("Generated")

    def updateTexture(self, testexture, buf, *args):
        testexture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.newtexture = testexture

    def on_a(self, instance, value):
        print('My property a changed to', value)
        self.label1.text = str(value)

    def on_newtexture(self, instance, value):
        self.img1.texture = value
        self.img1.canvas.ask_update()
        print("updated texture")
        print(value)
```

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. However, what I want is to update the UI from a sub-thread instead of the main thread. Is it impossible?

Comment: UI updates must be done on the main thread, but you can do everything else on a sub-thread, then just call a very small method (as in the above answer) using `Clock.schedule_once()` to put that small method back on the main thread.